# Rename initial string in filename

Tags: shell

I need to dynamically remove first part of name and copy to other locations. 
My file names are like

```
Voice_XYZZ_1_1801.pdf
Voice_XYZZ_1_1801.ndx
Electon_MNOPQ_1_1801.pdf
Electon_MNOPQ_1_1801.ndx
```

at run time either Voice can generate or Electon or both. 
I need to remove the initial part from file names and they should look like

```
XYZZ_1_1801.pdf
XYZZ_1_1801.ndx
MNOPQ_1_1801.pdf
MNOPQ_1_1801.ndx
```

Which command I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a shell from the Bourne family, you can remove the shortest leading substring matching up to and including an underscore from a filename  variable `f` using `${f#*_}`

Ex.

```
$ touch Voice_XYZZ_1_1801.pdf Voice_XYZZ_1_1801.ndx Electon_MNOPQ_1_1801.pdf Electon_MNOPQ_1_1801.ndx

$ for f in Voice_* Electon_*; do echo "${f#*_}"; done
XYZZ_1_1801.ndx
XYZZ_1_1801.pdf
MNOPQ_1_1801.ndx
MNOPQ_1_1801.pdf
```

You can use this along with the `mv` command to rename files e.g.

```
for f in Voice_* Electon_*; do mv "$f" "${f#*_}"; done
```

Copying to another location may be done similarly with the `cp` command e.g.

```
for f in Voice_* Electon_*; do cp "$f" "newdir/${f#*_}"; done
```

Comment: I ran command echo "{Voice_XYZZ_1_1801.pdf#*_}" ; 
and i am not getting expected result. All it showing me is full name of file in output.

Comment: @SHa that's not how it works: the syntax applies to *variable expansions* rather than literal strings i.e. you would need to do something like `str=Voice_XYZZ_1_1801.pdf ; echo "${str#*_}"`

Comment: This is what I have done in script.  
               for filename in `find . -iname '*.xml' -o -iname '*.ndx' -o -iname '*.pdf'`
               do
        Submission_Type = echo $filename | cut -d'_' -f 1 ;  
      FILE_NAME=$filename;
         FILE_NAME=echo "${FILE_NAME#*_}";
      mv "$FILE_NAME" "${FILE_NAME#*_}"; 

Is this is the right way?

Comment: The command work only for one file. if there are multiple files present then script fails while trying to change name of second file.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easily from the command-line by calling a Perl one-liner:

```
ls *_* | perl -ne 'chomp($_); $orig = $_; $_ =~ s/[^_]*_//; rename $orig,$_;'
```

Here's an explanation for the code:

- Send all the filenames that have '_' in their name to the next command

  ls *_* |
- For each of the strings being passed in, do the command

  perl -ne
- Remove the newline from the filename (leftover from running 'ls' command)

  chomp($_);
- Remove the first part of the word, searching until you find a '_'

  $_ =~ s/[^*]**//;
- Rename the file

  rename $orig,$_;

Comment: I am currently using KSH. Will it be fine to mix KSH and perl commands in same script?

Comment: The perl command is not working in .ksh script. I tried multiple times, but name never changes.

Comment: Hmm, I ran KSH and the command worked. Maybe add `print($_);` right before `chomp($_)` and see if it prints out more than one file. Also, you are using single quotes, and not double quotes, around the Perl command, right?

Comment: which Perl are you using? `perl -v`  Also, try running just the perl command on a single file with no other commands: `perl -e 'rename "Voice_XYZZ.pdf","XYZZ.pdf";'`